# In C#, Relfection incorrectly determines IsGenericType property for ByRef method argument

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

Could someone please explain why I see what I see (the screenshot of the console below)? For 'ref' and non-'ref' method argument I got different generic-related properties from Reflection. I'm using .NET 4.8 (classic .NET Framework).

```
public class MyClass {

    public class Aref
    {
        public virtual void method(object je, ref List<MyClass> batchlist, object doc)
        {
        }
    }


    public class A
    {
        public virtual void method(object je, List<MyClass> batchlist, object doc)
        {
        }
    }

    private static void WriteGenericProps(Type type)
    {
        var method = type.GetMethod(nameof(Aref.method));
        var param = method.GetParameters().First(p => p.Name == "batchlist");

        Console.WriteLine(nameof(param.ParameterType.IsByRef) + "=" + param.ParameterType.IsByRef);
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(param.ParameterType.IsGenericType) + "=" + param.ParameterType.IsGenericType);
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(param.ParameterType.ContainsGenericParameters) + "=" + param.ParameterType.ContainsGenericParameters);
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(param.ParameterType.IsConstructedGenericType) + "=" + param.ParameterType.IsConstructedGenericType);
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(param.ParameterType.IsGenericParameter) + "=" + param.ParameterType.IsGenericParameter);
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(param.ParameterType.IsGenericTypeDefinition) + "=" + param.ParameterType.IsGenericTypeDefinition);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = typeof(Aref);
        Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
        WriteGenericProps(t);
        Console.WriteLine();

        t = typeof(A);
        Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
        WriteGenericProps(t);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isgenerictype?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) for `IsGenericType` say:

> The `IsGenericType` property returns `false` if the immediate type is not generic. For example, an array whose elements are of type `A<int>` (`A(Of Integer)` in Visual Basic) is not itself a generic type.

You'll find you get the same result if `batchlist` is a `List<MyClass>[]` or a pointer.

If you've got a by-ref type, you'll need to call [`GetElementType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getelementtype?view=netframework-4.8) to get the underlying type. This gives you `typeof(List<MyClass>)`, which behaves as you're expecting.

Comment: I read Remarks section you refer to, before posting. But I still don't get it. ```List<MyClass> batchlist``` is neither an array nor a pointer. Or does by-ref mean "a pointer" in this case, because what actually happens behind the scenes is passing "a pointer" to the original reference into the method?

Comment: By-ref means "has `ref`". The Type object you're looking at represents `ref <Thing>`. You need to call `GetElementType()` to get the Type object for `<Thing>`.